# android splash screen

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen

i have a program that shows a splash screen.But the problem is whenever i refresh same page again it appears.Is there any method to stop splash screen again and again.I want it just comes at first time not again and again.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you basically want the splash screen appear once per app launch.
Here's a quick and dirty way:

1. Subclass `android.app.Application` as, say, `MyApp`;
2. Declare that class in `AndroidManifest.xml` (`<application android:name=".MyApp" ... >`) so that it would get instantiated at app launch time;
3. Give it a `public static boolean SPLASH_SHOWN = false;`
4. Now, in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` check if `SPLASH_SHOWN = false`, show splash and set it to `true`.

Comment: if (SPLASH_SHOWN == false)
        {
         splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);
         splash.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash);
         Message msg = new Message();
         msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
         splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME); 
         splash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         SPLASH_SHOWN=true;
       
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the splash screen in the same activity with another view layout (the main layout) - for example, display splash screen first, then swich the view to the main layout - I suggest to control the content view setting in `onResume()`.
Use a boolean variable (`displayedSplash`) to remember whether the splash screen has been displayed. If it has not been displayed (start the activity the first time, displayedSplash == false), then set the view to the splash screen, after that switch to the main layout and set `displayedSplash = true`. If it has been displayed (refresh the page, displayedSplash == true), just set the view to the main layout.

Another simple and safe solution for simple splash screen is implementing it as an activity, then start the main activity. When the `onResume()` is called the second time, just finish the activity. Please refer to [this Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/android-batsg/wiki/CreateSplashScreenActivity) for the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times I call finish() method inside onPause() method in splash activity. This will work fine for me